# Is it possible to deploy the Web App to Azure China by the Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-china

So far our team is using Azure DevOps to manage our code and we have created some pipelines to deploy the code to Web App in Azure Global (East Asia).
And now we need to deploy the code to Web App in Azure China.
Azure China is not totally same as Azure Global, we still want to create some new pipeline to do the deployment to Azure China, I want to know whether it can be achieved.

Comment: Hi @Ocean Sun Did you check out below answer, how did it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnot try it out myself. But it seems possible. You can refer to the detailed steps as described in this [documents](https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/articles/azure-operations-guide/app-service-web/aog-app-service-web-howto-deploy-via-vsts). Obviously the documents is little out of date, it gave an example for VSTS project which is the older version of Azure devops. But you can follow the steps and give it a shot.

The official site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/china/concepts-support#assisted-support-channels) lists below channels if you require assistance:

[Online submission](https://support.azure.cn/support/support-azure/)

[MSDN forum support](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-CN/home?forum=windowsazurezhchs&sort=lastpostdesc&brandIgnore=true&page=1) (in Chinese)

WeChat support (ID: VNET_AzureSupport)

Comment: Thanks, so far I have not started to do the deployment but I have succeed to create the service connections to Azure China by the valid service principals.